# Fastest way to test if any element in __m256 is non zero

Tags: x86, simd, intrinsics, avx

I have the result of a comparison between two __m256 vectors.

```
__m256 result = _mm256_cmp_ps( a, b, _CMP_GT_OQ );
```

At which point I have a vector result with 8 values.
And each of those values is either 0xffffffff or 0x00000000.

Now I want to know if all elements are zero.

In other words: did **all eight** elements fail the comparison?

What would be the fastest way to go about this? Either in AVX or AVX2 intrinsics.

Comment: `0 == _mm256_movemask_ps(result)` is 2 uops (movemask + macro-fused `test`+`jcc`.)  I'm sure this is a duplicate, will look for one.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but the general idea of movemask / integer compare is the best way.  Either against 0 for all-false, or against `0xff` for all-true, or whatever else.  (Always at least as good as `ptest` for dealing with `pcmp` / `cmpps` results, because `ptest` is multiple uops on all current x86 CPUs and can't macro-fuse with a `jcc` like integer `test` / `cmp` can).

Comment: I don't think lane is the correct term here, value may be better.

Comment: @MargaretBloom:  Yes.  ARM NEON uses "lane" where Intel terminology uses "element" to talk about the values in a SIMD vector.  In x86 terminology, "lane" usually means a 128-bit portion of a 256 or 512b vector, where that terminology is unfortunately needed because many AVX shuffles are "in-lane" and can't move data between lanes.